# Windows 10 UEV VDI - One Program fails to save settings for one user

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware-horizon-view, user-experience-virtualization

could use a pointer on this one.

We have UEV setup in a VMWare Horizon 7 environment. Settings Storage Location is on a FreeBSD based NAS that is bound to AD. We have a situation where ONE user's settings for PuTTY do not upload to the settings storage location. Saved settings apply without issue. I can modify the pkgx elsewhere, copy it to their settings storage location, and they get the changes. However, if they make a change to PuTTY settings it never attempts to push the settings up to the settings storage location on the NAS. No error in the logs, no success in the logs. It just doesn't happen.

What's even weirder is that I've seen a change they have made get uploaded ONCE.

Individual steps and puzzle pieces I've sorted out so far.

User can read data from Settings Storage Location -CONFIRMED

User can apply data from Settings Storage Location - CONFIRMED

Local changes made are detected - Probably confirmed: Local settings generates a "Current" and "Initial" folder with timestamps around login, but not later.

Local changes made are uploaded - Does not happen.

User can write to Settings Storage Location - Confirmed

Any ideas for further diagnostic steps would be great. I know they can read\write from the Settings Storage location. The UEV template works fine for other users for PuTTY, and other UEV templates work fine for this user. Oh, and I know they are writing registry keys in the directory the template is monitoring, because a manual registry export shows those keys being modified.

Also should note that because of the security requirements, I do not have a way to interact directly with their VDI session while this user is logged in. I can view event logs, and I can shadow them and watch their screen, but I have no method to enter admin credentials during their session.